# How to tell if a webhook request is in sandbox for DialogFlow V2?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I'm migrating to Dialogflow V2, and in V1 I could tell if this was a sandbox request by looking at:

```
request.body.originalRequest.data.isInSandbox
```

I cannot find the equivalent in V2, or in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:
request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.isInSandbox

Make sure you're trying it from Action on Google Simulator console (for example), not from Dialogflow Fulfillment console.

Regards,
Yury